# Is there any way to enable sketch tool automatically when I click the screenshot preview on Venture?

Tags: macos, screenshot, macos-ventura

Today I upgraded my Mac to Venture, it seems the sketch tool is not auto-enabled when I click the screenshot preview, which means I should click the markup tool option and sketch button manually. Prior to Venture, sketch tool is auto-enabled like iOS. Is there any way to recover that behavior? See [expected-default-behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26GHg.jpg)

Comment: Same question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451530/how-to-open-screenshot-in-markup-mode-by-default

Until now, no answer.